# How can I create MsSQL procedure for filtering one table based on two others?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, .net-core

I want to create procedure in Microsoft SQL Server.
I have following tables

- User - UserId (PK), FirstName, LastName...
- Skill - SkillId (PK), Name
- UserSkill - UserSkillId (PK), UserId (FK), NameId (FK)
- Profession - ProfessionId (PK), Name
- UserProfession - UserProfessionId (PK), UserId (FK), ProfessionId (FK)
- Interest - InterestId (PK), Name
- UserInterest - UserInterestId (PK), UserId (FK), InterestId (FK)

I want to create stored procedure that will receive Ids of skills, interests and professions as parameters, and that procedure should return all users that contains all skills, interests and professions that are passed as parameters. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: I presume that this is for Microsoft SQL Server, but you don't specify.  Please confirm exactly which platform this is for; MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Use UDT, JSON, Arrays for parameters whatever avaliable in your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server...

MOCK UP OF TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
  id    INT,
  name  NVARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT INTO app_user VALUES (1, 'User_One'), (2, 'User_Two');

CREATE TABLE skill (
  id    INT,
  name  NVARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT INTO skill VALUES (1, 'Skill_One'), (2, 'Skill_Two'), (3, 'Skill_Three');

CREATE TABLE profession (
  id    INT,
  name  NVARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT INTO profession VALUES (1, 'Prof_One'), (2, 'Prof_Two'), (3, 'Prof_Three');

CREATE TABLE interest (
  id    INT,
  name  NVARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT INTO interest VALUES (1, 'Int_One'), (2, 'Int_Two'), (3, 'Int_Three');

CREATE TABLE user_skill (
  user_id   INT,
  skill_id  INT
)
INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3);

CREATE TABLE user_profession (
  user_id        INT,
  profession_id  INT
)
INSERT INTO user_profession VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3);

CREATE TABLE user_interest (
  user_id      INT,
  interest_id  INT
)
INSERT INTO user_interest VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3);
```

DATA TYPE FOR PARAMETERS, AND STORED PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE TYPE identifier_list AS TABLE ( id INT );

CREATE PROCEDURE get_users
  @skill_id_list        identifier_list READONLY,
  @profession_id_list   identifier_list READONLY,
  @interest_id_list     identifier_list READONLY
AS
  WITH
    user_by_skill
  AS
  (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM user_skill
INNER JOIN @skill_id_list  filter
        ON filter.id = user_skill.skill_id
  GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @skill_id_list)
  ),
    user_by_profession
  AS
  (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM user_profession
INNER JOIN @profession_id_list  filter
        ON filter.id = user_profession.profession_id
  GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @profession_id_list)
  ),
    user_by_interest
  AS
  (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM user_interest
INNER JOIN @interest_id_list  filter
        ON filter.id = user_interest.interest_id
  GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @interest_id_list)
  )
  SELECT
    app_user.*
  FROM
    app_user
  INNER JOIN
    user_by_skill
      ON user_by_skill.user_id = app_user.id
  INNER JOIN
    user_by_profession
      ON user_by_profession.user_id = app_user.id
  INNER JOIN
    user_by_interest
      ON user_by_interest.user_id = app_user.id
  ;
```

EXAMPLE USE-CASE:

```
DECLARE @skills identifier_list;
INSERT @skills VALUES (1), (2);

DECLARE @interests identifier_list;
INSERT @interests VALUES (2), (3);

DECLARE @professions identifier_list;
INSERT @professions VALUES (1), (3);

EXEC get_users @skills, @professions, @interests
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1970babe4ebb70c1e402f9ebfae03fd7

Comment: Or, using `INTERSECT` : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=284f3a6fc671c00aaf37053e3c79852d

Comment: I have only one more problem now. If I don't pass any skill for example, procedure will return none of users. The way it should work is if I don't pass any skill, procedure should not filter users by skills.

Comment: @amircokoja - Without having time to think about it, you could just use `LEFT JOIN` then replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(filter.id)`...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2a55cce3bdbf559bf32cba780bb39bc

Comment: @amircokoja - Or, perhaps... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=309048095656dbd07d3dd1c6ba2972e0